# javascript image toggling

Tags: .net, javascript

I have a tree view which has a folder icon by default and once clicked it has to be changed to a checkbox icon. And further on clicking the checkbox icon should display a folder icon.

**Sample Code:**

---

Server side code: C#

```
htmlSb.AppendFormat("<li><span class=\"folder\"
   onclick=\"javascript:return Test.Controls.TreeView.SelectNode('"
   + this.Id
   + "',this);\">{0}</span></li>", emptyContent);
```

---

JavaScript code:

```
var Test= new Object();
Test.Controls=new Object();
Test.Controls.TreeView = new Object();

Test.Controls.TreeView.SelectNode = function (TreeId, nodeLabel) {
    $("#" + TreeId + " li span, ul li span").css("background-color", "transparent");
    nodeLabel.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    nodeLabel.style.background = "url(../images/selected.gif) 0 0 no-repeat";
}
```

---

The other Image :

```
if (nodeLabel.style.background = "url(../images/folderclosed.gif)  0 0 no-repeat")
```

I need to toggle between `"selected.gif"` and `"folderclosed.gif"` images. If one is clicked the other should display. and vice versa.

Please help.

Comment: Sorry Alex, I am a new member and I wasn't aware of this.I've now marked the accepted answers. 

Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have jQuery available to you. This should do the trick:

```
// get a jquery object for the node label
var $nodeLabel = $(nodeLabel);

if ($nodeLabel.data('background') == '' || $nodeLabel.data('background') == 'folderclosed') {
  // if the node label has no background data set or is set to folderclosed, set to selected
  $nodeLabel.data('background', 'selected').css('background', 'url(../images/selected.gif) 0 0 no-repeat');
} else {
  // if the node label is set to selected, set to folderclosed
  $nodeLabel.data('background', 'folderclosed').css('background', 'url(../images/folderclosed.gif)  0 0 no-repeat');
}
```

Comment: The browser says the object doesn't support this property
$nodelabel.data. Am I missing any jquery js file. I have jquery.js,jquerytreeview.js,jquerycookie.js refered

Comment: The data function is included in the core, so you should not need anything other than jquery.js for that functionality. Not sure which treeview plugin you are using, but did you check out the one at bassistance.de? It appears to have the functionality you are looking for built in. Here is the link http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-treeview/

Answer (score 0):

sounds like the jQuery toggle function would be easiest since it's designed for just this.

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/